# How can I hide posts written by a specific author in LinkedIn Pulse?

Tags: linkedin

I'd like to hide posts written by a specific author in [LinkedIn Pulse](http://www.linkedin.com/today/).

Answer (score 1):

Hover over the top line and a "Hide" link appears on the right, click that.

Comment: Unfortunately, Pulse doesn't seem to have this option. (I use hide a lot for contacts). Do you see a "Hide" link appears on the right with Pulse?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. The news part itself is filled with things that LinkedIn think you should see. You can adjust some of the content by using the dropdown and go to settings or you can kill it altogether by using a hack but that is it.